# Blocking call in @KafkaListener spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor

When I am using spring @KafkaListener is there any difference if I subscribe to reactive flow:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-name", groupId = "group-id", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consume(org.springframework.messaging.Message<Message<?>> message){
    reactiveService.doSmth().subscribe();
}
```

or just block it:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-name", groupId = "group-id", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consume(org.springframework.messaging.Message<Message<?>> message){
    reactiveService.doSmth().block();
}
```

ReactiveService.class

```
public Mono<String> doSmth() {
  ...
}
```

Per my understanding @KafkaListener has no interaction with reactor netty threads and uses its own task executor to create threads, meaning I can use any of this approach without getting any performance loss?

PS: I know that there is reactive KafkaListener support, but currently I am bound to regular @KafkaListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subscribe()` may cause an execution of your reactive stream on a different thread. The `block()` will indeed block this `consume()` method until your reactive stream is fulfilled. This definitely may impact the Kafka Consumer thread where we have to return from our execution withing `max.poll.interval.ms` to keep our consumer alive. Otherwise it is treated as idle and group rebalance may occur. See more info in docs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#max-poll-interval-ms